# ruby-kafka idle timeout handler to call deliver_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, idle-timer, ruby-kafka

Is there a way in ruby-kafka to call deliver_messages on the producer after a certain producer idle timeout? I delivering messages when the buffer_size > n. I would like to clear the buffer if there are no new messages to the producer after idle time 't' and the buffer is at (n - x) where n > x

Tried to add a handler for ruby kafka client producer idle time. No success yet.